# Access files through path in webpart

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I need to create a custom webpart for a kentico project. I added a property to the webpart that sets the path to the images. The user needs to file in the path to the folder he wants (see screenshot, this can be the path)

[image]

But i'm stuck now in de codebehind of my webpart. How can i get the full path in codebehind, get all the images and add for each image an  on my webpart.

I can't show much code, because i only got the basic of the webpart (property). I couldn't find an example of this on the net, and ilooked in existing webparts of kentico, but didn't find anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me which item you actually need help with.

- Are you having trouble setting the property value in your webpart
- Are you unable to get a correct value from the webpart property
- Are you unable to get the documents

In regards to getting a list of documents, use either of the following types to accomplish this.

The TreeHelper or TreeProvider class.

Comment: I want to make a custom control and show an image in that control. What property do i use for this: image, pâth,... and how can i access the image in de code behind of the webpart so i can show it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your WebPart make sure you are using a Form Control (CMSSiteManager/Development/Form Controls) that allows you to select paths. Something like "Single path selector". 
Then in your code behind you will create a property with the same name as the column name set when using the form control.

In your described case all the images will be nodes under the node tree so you can call them something like that:

```
string folder = "/images/%"; // this will be populated from WebPart via a property
List<string> paths = new List<string>();
TreeProvider treeProvider = new TreeProvider();
TreeNodeDataSet imageNodes = treeProvider.SelectNodes(CMSContext.CurrentSiteName, folder, CMSContext.PreferredCultureCode, false);
foreach (TreeNode imageNode in imageNodes)
{
    string path = ValidationHelper.GetString(imageNode["YourImageColumnName"], "");
    if (path.Length > 0)
    {
        paths.Add(path);
    }
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

For each property of webpart you can create public properties in code behind and and use get and set.
for example,
Suppose, I have a webpart property `ImagePath`
then in code behind

```
 public string ImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("ImagePath"),defaultPath);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue("ImagePath", value);
        }
    }
```

and you can use this public property in your code behind